# How do I remove the current directory (".") from my PATH?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, path

I recently updated OSX to El Capitan, and in the process of running through the steps needed to update my development environment, I discovered something rather disturbing: bash is behaving as if `.` is in my `PATH`, even though it's not. This is a serious security issue, and I can't find any way to turn it off.

Here's the result of `echo $PATH`:

`/Users/username/.rbenv/shims:/Users/username/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/Users/username/.pyenv/shims:/opt/chefdk/bin:/Users/username/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin:/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin:/Users/username/.pyenv/bin:/Users/username/.rbenv/bin:/Users/username/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin::/Users/username/bin:/src/workspace/s3-utils/bin:/opt/local/lib/oracle:::/Users/username/bin/IAMCli/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

Notice how `.` is missing from that listing? With that in mind, why is this happening?

`[10:26:57][username@flint:~/Downloads] :)
$ ls script.sh
ls: script.sh: No such file or directory
[10:27:08][username@flint:~/Downloads] :( Exit code: 1
$ which script.sh
[10:27:09][username@flint:~/Downloads] :( Exit code: 1
$ touch script.sh
[10:27:15][username@flint:~/Downloads] :)
$ chmod +x script.sh
[10:27:19][username@flint:~/Downloads] :)
$ which script.sh
./script.sh
[10:27:23][username@flint:~/Downloads] :)
$`

Somehow, `.` is in my path, even though I did not configure it so, and `$PATH` doesn't include it. What do I do about this?

Comment: What happens if you replace the `:::` after oracle and the `::` after ruby-build/bin with plain `:`?

Comment: is there a user name .rbenv created by Ruby installation, attach a screenshot of your Users and Groups

Comment: . never needs to be in path. if you call an executable without a path, and one exists in the current working directory, it will be executed. perhaps I'm misunderstanding your issue, because that behavior is not anything abnormal, and goes back to the 60's. literally Every OS I've ever used functioned this way.

Comment: @FrankThomas Your OSs have been dangerously misconfigured, then. Having `.` in your path leaves you open to malicious code running without your knowledge. Someone could stick a script into your working directory called `sudo`, and any time you used sudo, you'd unknowingly be giving your password to that script, instead of the real `/usr/bin/sudo` command. Not having `.` in your path means that when you want to execute something in your current directory, you have to acknowledge that by using `./command` instead of `command`. Also, your second comment about $PATH evaluation is simply wrong.

Comment: @Law29 That was it! Bash was treating the duplicated colons as if they indicated that `.` should be in my PATH. I can't imagine why, though...

Comment: @FrankThomas, if I remember correctly (It’s been years!) that’s true on Windows, going all the way back to MS-DOS.  It’s never been true on any UNIX-like operating system.

Comment: As an aside, whenever printing the contents of a PATH variable, I format them one directory per line; it makes them WAY more readable.  In your case, it would have shown the empty directories resulting from multiple colons: `echo $PATH | tr : \\n`

Answer (score 0):

As Law29 pointed out in a comment, my problem was those instances of duplicated colons. For some reason, Bash appears to treat `::` in your PATH as if it were `:.:`.

This seems like a bug, as I can't imagine why anyone would want that.

Comment: From the man page for bash under Shell Variables, PATH "The  search  path for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands. ... A  zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory. ...".  It's not a bug, does than leave a failure of imagination?

Comment: While I agree that it's clearly not a bug, I'm not sure that just because it's the default makes it *desirable*. I don't want that to be the default, because having `.` in your path is potentially dangerous. A much more sensible default would be to simple ignore blank directory names.

Comment: For the record, this is true in zsh as well.  I don’t know whether this behaviour is merely “traditional”, or whether there’s a good reason for it.  At any rate, I define this shell function to clean out all non-existing _or_ blank directories from a `PATH`-like variable, and then call it on such variables at the end of my shell initialisation:  `pathclean() {for p in $@; eval "$p=(\$^$p(-/N))"}`.  Not sure if that’d work verbatim in Bash, but you’re welcome to try…

Comment: In retrospect, that definitely won’t work in bash since it depends on the fact that zsh automatically ties the `$PATH` environment variable to the `$path` array.